# SQL Count and Duplicates

Tags: sql

Assume a small town is holding elections, each citizen gets to vote as many times as they want, but their vote gets split the more times they vote, and they cannot do duplicate votes.

```
Voter   Vote
---------------
Jane    Jane
Howard  Jane
John    Howard
John    Howard
Jane    John
Sara    Howard
```

How would you in a SQL query determine who the winner was?

I'm a basic user so all I got is

```
SELECT  
    vote, COUNT( vote) 
FROM 
    table1 
GROUP BY
    vote
```

This doesn't account for the duplicates or the splitting of the votes.

Help?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e569/9)

Comment: SELECT  vote,COUNT(distinct voter) FROM table1 group by vote

Comment: How do you define "split"? Are the votes split evenly? That is, if a voter votes n times, does each vote get count as 1/n?

Comment: You say - "they cannot do duplicate votes" but your example has duplicates.

Comment: I think you need some "ORDER BY" logic in your examples. In other words, perhaps a DATE, or a "Vote Cast Sequence" ... something so you know what the first vote was for each voter (hence full weight), and less weight for subsequent votes ..  For example, Jane voted for both Jane and John .. but which one gets full weight, and which half ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamically created table

```
 select vote, count(*) 
 from 
     (select distinct voter, vote 
      from table1) as t
 group by vote
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT V.vote, SUM(W.weight) AS votes
FROM 
(
SELECT  voter, CAST(1 AS FLOAT) / COUNT(vote) AS weight
FROM table1 
group by voter
) W
JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT vote, voter
FROM table1 
) V ON W.voter = V.voter
GROUP BY V.vote
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select vote, sum(1 / votes) as result from 
(SELECT voter, count(*) as votes from Table1 group by voter) votecount 
INNER JOIN Table1 on votecount.voter = Table1.voter
group by vote
order by result desc
```

this handles duplictaes in the way that one voter can give 2/3 and 1/3 votes

**EDIT**
added order by

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct voter and vote combination to remove duplicate votes

```
SELECT vote,COUNT(distinct voter) FROM table1 group by vote
```

Answer (score 0):

You may determine the appropriate weight of each voter's vote via subquery.

```
SELECT t1.vote AS 'Candidate', CAST(SUM(t2.`weight`) AS Decimal(6,2)) as 'Votes' 
FROM table1 AS t1 RIGHT JOIN (
 SELECT voter, 1.0 / CAST( COUNT(*) as Decimal) as `weight` 
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY voter 
) AS t2 ON t1.voter = t2.voter 
GROUP BY t1.vote 
ORDER BY t1.vote;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e569/48